# Finding the gradient using finite differentiation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

How do you find the gradient of $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$ using finite differentiation?

I know if I find it normally, the gradient is the unit vector $\hat{r}$. But how do I use finite differentiation to find it?
$$
g_i = \frac{f(x_0 + h e_i) − f(x_0)}{h}, 
$$
where
$$
e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad 
e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \quad 
e_3 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: In the future, please format mathematics in posts. LaTeX/MathJax tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The gradient will be $[\partial r / \partial x,\partial r / \partial y,\partial r / \partial z]^T$

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if I understand correctly.
Consider $i=1$, then
$$
g_1 = \left.\frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^2+y^2+z^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{h}\right|_{h=0}
$$
and
\begin{align}
& \frac{\sqrt{(x+h)^2+y^2+z^2}-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}{h} = \\
    &= \frac{[(x+h)^2+y^2+z^2]-[x^2+y^2+z^2]}{h\left[\sqrt{(x+h)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right]} = \\
    &= \frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h\left[\sqrt{(x+h)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right]} = \\ 
    &= \frac{2hx+h^2}{h\left[\sqrt{(x+h)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\right]} = \\ 
    &= \frac{2x+h}{\sqrt{(x+h)^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} = \\ 
\end{align}
for $h=0$ it becomes
$$
g_1 = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} 
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$(\nabla\phi)(x,y,z)=\lim_{h\to 0}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\phi(x+h,y,z)-\phi(x-h,y,z)}{2h} \\ \frac{\phi(x,y+h,z)-\phi(x,y-h,z)}{2h} \\ \frac{\phi(x,y,z+h)-\phi(x,y,z-h)}{2h}\end{bmatrix}$$

Or, if you would prefer it in vector notation form,
$$(\nabla\phi)(\boldsymbol x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\phi(\boldsymbol x+h\boldsymbol e_1)-\phi(\boldsymbol x-h\boldsymbol e_1)}{2h} \\ \frac{\phi(\boldsymbol x+h\boldsymbol e_2)-\phi(\boldsymbol x-h\boldsymbol e_2)}{2h}\\\frac{\phi(\boldsymbol x+h\boldsymbol e_3)-\phi(\boldsymbol x-h\boldsymbol e_3)}{2h}\end{bmatrix}$$

Use whatever small value for $h$ that you would like.